# Как отправлять данные из формы html (django) в telegram chat

Tags: python, django, telebot

Я писал код на php с помощью которого удавалось отправлять данные из формы в chat, не могу реализовать это на python. Вот html код:

```html
<form action="form.py">
            <h3>форма</h3>
            <input type="text" name="name" value="имя" onblur="if(this.value.length == 0) this.value = 'имя'" onfocus="if(this.value == 'имя') this.value = '' "/><br>
            <input type="text" name="fname"value="фамилия" onblur="if(this.value.length == 0) this.value = 'фамилия'" onfocus="if(this.value == 'фамилия') this.value = '' "/><br>
            <textarea name="msg" onblur="if(this.value.length == 0) this.value = 'отчество'" onfocus="if(this.value == 'отчество') this.value=''">отчество</textarea>
            <p class="send">
                <input type="submit" value="ОТПРАВИТЬ"  />
```

Answer (score 0):

В html передаёте данные с forms или views В инпут id и username передаёте данные .

```
<form method="post"> - измените метод отправки
```

```
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input name="username" id="username" type="text" class="login-from__login "
 
      <button type="submit" disabled class="login-from__submit">
```